# Is Lebesgue point always finite value?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

For a locally integrable function in $\Bbb{R}^d$.A point $\bar{x}\in \Bbb{R}^d$ lies in the Lebesgue set of $f$ if:

$$\lim _{m_{\bar{x}} \in \vec{B} \atop 0} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_{B}|f(y)-f(\bar{x})| d y=0$$

The question is :Is the Lebesgue point always has finite value ($f(\bar{x})<\infty$)?

In Stein's real analysis book,this point is specified,but in Rudin's and Folland's book,this point is not specified,but I guess it's just an implicit assumption here since if it's not the $|f(y)-f(\bar{x})|$ may not be well defined?Correct?

Comment: It seems very reasonable to me to assume that $f$ is not assumed to take values in the extended reals for this, so that $f$ has "finite value" at $\overline{x}$.  I would assume this of almost any theorem. Often in these types of books, extensions to more general functions are explicitly flagged and when not explicitly called out are not intended. I do no have Rudin or Folland at hand and cannot verify as to the references you point to, but generally the spirit is to assume everything is real-valued (maybe unbounded on some domain, but real valued at any point) and not-extendedly-real-valued.

Comment: @leslie townes thanks . What's the motivation to introduce extended value function in integration theory? Since all the books will mention this type of function?

Comment: It must be finite. Otherwise the limit would be infinite.

Comment: @copper.hat since the formula $|f(y)  - f(\bar{x})|$ needs to be well defined only when $f(y) $ is finite or oppositie sign as the infinite $f(\bar{x})$ correct?  Hence $|f(y)  - f(\bar{x})| = + \infty$  which means the integral is infinite correct?

Comment: Since the limit is finite the integrand must be finite ae. The integrand would be infinite or undefined if $f(\bar{x})$ was infinite.